# Почему Hibernate не видит .hbm.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня объекты `Task` должны записываться в таблицу `tasks`:

Но получаю ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not
>   found : ru.pravvich.model.Task.hbm.xml :
>   origin(ru.pravvich.model.Task.hbm.xml)

Что у меня нет мапинга хотя все мне кажется настроено, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, где я ошибся. Вот все мои конфигурации:

Объект:

```
public class Task {
    private int id;
    private String desc;
    private Timestamp create;
    private boolean done; 
    //гетеры и сеттеры... 
}
```

Есть конфигурационный файл `hibernate.cfg.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/todo_list</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>

        <mapping resource="ru.pravvich.model.Task.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

По соответствующему адресу `ru.pravvich.model.Task.hbm.xml` есть файл:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping">
    <class name="ru.pravvich.model.Task">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="desc" column="description" />
        <property name="done" column="done" />
        <property name="create" column="create_time" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

И лежит он правильно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке запустить вот таким образом:

```
final SessionFactory factory =
       new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

final Session session = factory.openSession();

final Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
final Task task2 = new Task(3, "todo3",
            new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), false);
session.save(task2);
session.close();
factory.close();
```

И таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    done BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    create_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: А если путь прописать через / : `<mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/Task.hbm.xml" />` работает?

Comment: @MrFylypenko да заработало спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нет имени таблицы поэтому hibernate не знает где база данных

```
[ class name="ru.pravvich.model.Task" table="tasks">  ]
```

Comment: Судя по комментарию, ТС решил задачу. Пожалуйста дайте более подробный ответ  и обоснуйте, почему ваше решение полезно.